# Put absolute position in Three.js, all objects in 0,0,0 position

Tags: javascript, three.js, coordinates

Please go to put this question as a duplicate because the solutions that do not work to me, and really am new to Three.js.

I have several objects in the scene, http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-captura-9426000.html It is a map but each region is an object and are on the plane according to their positions. But now I want to put all these objects in a single coordinate, example in the 0,0,0 and that they are all together. but if I put municipios[i].position.set (0,0,0), it is in the same position. As I do so that it is in the actual position in the Cartesian plane?

This is roughly the code that I have.

```
                            for(i in $scope.datosMunicipio){


                            Geometria[i]=new THREE.Geometry();
                            array_extrude[i]=new Array();
                              for (var a  in  vector_lat[i]){

                                 if(a!=0){
                                    if(vector_lat[i][a]==vector_lat[i][a-1]) {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                 }
                                    Vector[i]=new THREE.Vector3((vector_long[i][a]+75.5)*10,((vector_lat[i][a])-5.5)*10,0);
                                    Geometria[i].vertices.push(Vector[i]);  
                                    array_extrude[i].push(Vector[i]);

                                }

                            forma_figura[i]=new THREE.Shape(array_extrude[i]);

                            extrude_geometria[i]=new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(forma_figura[i],datos_extrusion); // lento
                            materialFront[i] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: "#FF0000",name:$scope.datosMunicipio[i].nombre} );

                            municipios[i] = new THREE.Mesh( extrude_geometria[i], materialFront[i] );
```

the charge data database, municipios[i] in each position has a region. coordinates are data google maps, long and latitude respectively, in the case of these figures are in the range 5.5 ... and -75 .....
Each region has its own 0,0,0 as I do that all regions are in the same 0,0,0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all your geometries already share the same coordinate system. They start at 0,0,0 so moving them there just sends them "home."

If you call `extrude_geometria[i].computeBoundingBox()` this will set the geometry's range values. To get all the geometries to move to coincident locations, set each to the center of the bounding box. This operation is similar to the geometry `.center()` method.

```
municipios[i].geometry.computeBoundingBox();
var offset = municipios[i].geometry.boundingBox.center().negate();
municipios[i].position.copy(offset);
```

Comment: Thanks friend, but I still get the desired effect, that is to say that each region want this at 0,0,0 and later moved from any region that position I want, or I to move a particular region of municipalities [i ] at a given coordinate such municipalities [24] .position.set (5,0,0), but being real coordinate.

Comment: anyone know how I can do what I need?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not understanding your desire. Could you add an illustration of what you actually want?